# Do homotopy equivalences operate over discrete spaces?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

My understanding is limited and I'm trying to learn more about how homotopy forms the notion of equivalence. I can grasp its definition as "continuous", but my understanding of homotopy falls away in spaces that are discrete. How does the mapping actually work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two discrete spaces are homotopy equivalent if and only if they have the same number of points. Any function whose domain is discrete is automatically continuous, and two functions $X \to Y$ for discrete $Y$ are homotopic if and only if they are equal.

(I'm not sure I understood your question, let me know if that clears things up or not.)

Comment: My confusion is stemming from "Any function whose domain is discrete is automatically continuous". How is this possible? My understanding was that discrete is not continuous in analysis. I get that it changes in topology somehow. Could you elaborate on how that changes so I can fully understand your answer?

Comment: @Holographic: By definition, a function between topological spaces is continuous iff preimage of every open subset of the codomain space is open in the domain space. In a discrete space, every set is open.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but let me cast some light (or maybe not) for future readers.
Instead of looking at homotopy in discrete spaces, it works better looking to define a homotopy between graphs, so you could identify the form, or at least the connections between discrete objects, graphs inherit a topology by it's connection to groups, so it shouldn't be that hard. 
If I could say that something involving graphs is easy, which I can not, but like I've said before, this is just to cast some light in the subject.

Comment: The pseudocircle is a good example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle

Comment: This is a old comment and by now I would still reaffirm that graphs may provide a good framework for the subject, but I would add lattices and posets, wich are higly correlated, as good structures too, since althoug they don't inherit a topology from semigroups as graphs do, their own structure provides a good framework to a lot of aspects in the theory and can be more easily studied in a categorical perspective, which fits better for algebraic topology.